# pygame not installing correctly on Windows cmd

Tags: python, cmd, pygame

I m trying to download pygame on Windows 10 cmd but the same error keeps ocurring. I ve already tried to downgrade pip and install pygame with a previous version, but it won t let me. I ve also tied to install setup tools, following this post:
[https://appuals.com/command-python-setup-py-egg_info/#:~:text=Fix%3A%20'Command%20%E2%80%9Cpython%20setup,code%201'%20When%20Installing%20Python&text=The%20error%20code%201%20is,to%20be%20installed%20or%20updated](https://appuals.com/command-python-setup-py-egg_info/#:%7E:text=Fix%3A%20%27Command%20%E2%80%9Cpython%20setup,code%201%27%20When%20Installing%20Python&text=The%20error%20code%201%20is,to%20be%20installed%20or%20updated).

This is the error i get when running **pip install pygame**

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [74 lines of output]


      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration...

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
          h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\http\client.py", line 1279, in request
          self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\http\client.py", line 1325, in _send_request
          self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\http\client.py", line 1274, in endheaders
          self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\http\client.py", line 1034, in _send_output
          self.send(msg)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\http\client.py", line 974, in send
          self.connect()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\http\client.py", line 1441, in connect
          super().connect()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\http\client.py", line 945, in connect
          self.sock = self._create_connection(
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
          raise err
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
          sock.connect(sa)
      TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o9hfyjxb\pygame_239c608394e64fd48c2ecb4a4f0a02d8\setup.py", line 359, in <module>
          buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
        File "C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o9hfyjxb\pygame_239c608394e64fd48c2ecb4a4f0a02d8\buildconfig\config.py", line 225, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
        File "C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o9hfyjxb\pygame_239c608394e64fd48c2ecb4a4f0a02d8\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 497, in main
          and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
        File "C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o9hfyjxb\pygame_239c608394e64fd48c2ecb4a4f0a02d8\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 290, in ask
          update(x86=x86, x64=x64)
        File "C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o9hfyjxb\pygame_239c608394e64fd48c2ecb4a4f0a02d8\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 273, in update
          download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64)
        File "C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o9hfyjxb\pygame_239c608394e64fd48c2ecb4a4f0a02d8\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 124, in download_prebuilts
          download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
        File "C:\Users\isaac\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o9hfyjxb\pygame_239c608394e64fd48c2ecb4a4f0a02d8\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 54, in download_sha1_unzip
          response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
          response = self._open(req, data)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
          result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\urllib\request.py", line 1389, in https_open
          return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\urllib\request.py", line 1349, in do_open
          raise URLError(err)
      urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder>
      Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip ed561079ec622b0bab5a9e02976f5d540b0622da
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27

      ---
      For help with compilation see:
          https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
      To contribute to pygame development see:
          https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
      ---

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdUZArA-kZw

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip3 install pygame` if still not working do `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip'`